# Replacing the NaN and Inf Values

Tags: matlab

I am doing feature extraction for a data set, while calculating the slope feature, its value is sometimes float number or NaN or -ve it +ve Inf.

```
example { 1.525474574, NaN , -1.056217 ,-Inf , Inf }
```

the NaN and Inf values causes a problem while training the system, so i am planing to replace their values with numeric values, but i don't with what values should i replace them ?

if i found Inf, should i replace it with large number ?  and -Inf by very small ? , what about NaN ?

any help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is this is not a matlab question. I am not even sure it is a progamming question, but perhaps this helps:

If you really want to keep incorrect values in your data, you should replace them with the most meaningfull substitute. (Though of course you would preferably prevent these values from coming into existance at all)

Without knowledge of how those values became `NaN` for example, there is no way to say what the  'best' way is to deal with them.

---

My thought: If you don't know what you are dealing with, just remove them, don't try to 'fix' them as you may do more harm than good.

Comment: i am using Matlab to process my data set, i am calculating the slope these are the results of dividing ydiff / xdiff

Comment: @ahmedabobakr And what is the meaning of the slope if there is no difference in x? Unless you have a good answer to that you should not include those cases in your training.

Comment: @ahmedabobakr I agree with Dennis on this. If you introduce values (however fitting they seem), you are altering your solution. Those `NaN`s and `Inf`s have a reason, which is directly related to your representation of the problem.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin yes there are divisions by 0 and 0/0 so i decided that the slope is not appropriate feature in my case. thank you